# using list or range in numpy as row

Tags: python, numpy

How can I use range in numpy to get the cell in a area? I can use `from:to` but it is possible for me to use a list to set the row range?

```
import numpy as np
mx = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
print(mx)
print(mx[1:3, 2:4])
k = 1
print(mx[range(k, k+3), range(k+1, k+5)])
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use `range` or `arange` in that way (though see [@hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601568/6671176)), but you could use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), which uses the same syntax as range (*i.e.* you give it a start, a stop, and optionally a step argument):

```
mx[slice(k, k+3), slice(k+1,k+5)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
mx[k:k+3, k+1:k+5]
```

For example:

```
>>> mx[slice(k, k+3), slice(k+1,k+5)]
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [17, 18, 19]])

>>> mx[k:k+3, k+1:k+5]
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [17, 18, 19]])
```

For more info see also the [glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) for `slice` objects

Comment: Actually, `mx[1:3,2:4]` seems the simplest here.

Answer (score 1):

To use a list or array in indexing 2d, you need to think in terms of `broadcasting`:

```
In [263]: mx = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
In [264]: mx[1:3, 2:4]
Out[264]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [12, 13]])
In [265]: mx[np.arange(1,3)[:,None], np.arange(2,4)]
Out[265]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [12, 13]])
```

`np.ix_` makes that easier:

```
In [266]: np.ix_(np.arange(1,3), np.arange(2,4))
Out[266]: 
(array([[1],
        [2]]), array([[2, 3]]))
In [267]: mx[np.ix_(np.arange(1,3), np.arange(2,4))]
Out[267]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [12, 13]])
```

or the same thing with lists:

```
In [268]: mx[[[1],[2]], [2,3]]
Out[268]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [12, 13]])
```

This is indexing rows 1 and 2, and columns 2 and 3 - in a cartesian sense, not pairwise.

```
In [269]: mx[[1,2], [2,3]]     # diagonal of the block
Out[269]: array([ 7, 13])
```